# WorldPop Export to Drive clip in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip

How I can export to drive a clipped part of a WorldPop image, I'm using the following code but crush ....

```
// clip fun
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(export_geometry_2);
};


var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop").map(clipToCol)
                .filterDate('2017');
var population = dataset.select('population');
var populationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 50.0,
  palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50'],
};
Map.setCenter(113.643, 34.769, 7);
Map.addLayer(population, populationVis, 'Population');

Export.image.toDrive({
image: dataset.select('population'),
description: 'worldPop',
scale: 100,
region: export_geometry_2
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below a reproducible example. The example you have given uses variables that are not defined.

```
// Define ply geometry 
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[113.29693066406253,32.978167214883634],
                                   [119.66900097656253,32.978167214883634],
                                   [119.66900097656253,36.20607892441336],
                                   [113.29693066406253,36.20607892441336],
                                   [113.29693066406253,32.978167214883634]])
// Define clip tool 
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry);
};

// Define WorldPop & clip using function 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop").map(clipToCol)
                .filterDate('2017');

// Mosaic dataset
var mosaic = dataset.select('population').mosaic();

// Define colour scheme 
var populationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 50.0,
  palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50'],
};

// Set map centre
Map.setCenter(113.643, 34.769, 7);

// Add layer to map 
Map.addLayer(mosaic , populationVis, 'Population');

// Export to GDrive
Export.image.toDrive({
image: mosaic,
description: 'worldPop',
scale: 100,
region: geometry
})
```

Simply follow this [link to run this script in Google Earth Engine](https://code.earthengine.google.com/735e5cb1df693b9aab6a901a3a11880c)

After running this script, the `Tasks` tab will be highlighted. You must click on this and the task to define where you would like to store this export in Google Drive / other file storage system.

Please accept the answer if this fullfils your answer.

Comment: This task fails, as you try to export an imageCollection. Convert it to an image using a reducer or mosaic function (e.g. `dataset.select('population').mosaic()`)

Comment: Your're correct, the image does not export into Drive. I have updated my answer by adding the var mosaic.